# equation for velocity vs displacement for nonlinear acceleration

Tags: kinematics

An object starts out at t=0, s=0 and accelerates with A=sin(pi*t/T), where
T is defined as (pi/2 * Vmax/Amax).  Vmax is maximum velocity, and
Amax is maximum acceleration.  Solution is restricted to t=0 to t=T

The velocity equation is v(t) = 0.5Vmax(1-cos(pi*t/T))

What I am trying to solve is velocity as a function of displacement, v(s).

In other words, without having access to elapsed time, I am trying to generate an equation for velocity as a function of the observed displacement.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the acceleration $a = \sin \left( \frac{\pi t}{T}\right) $, by integration you get

$$ v(t)  = \int_0^t a\,{\rm d}t = \frac{T}{2} \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{T}\right) \right) $$
$$ s(t) = \int_0^t v\,{\rm d}t = \frac{T}{\pi^2} \left(\pi t - T \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{T}\right) \right) $$

Since the last one *cannot* be inverted for $t(s)$, we can invert the first one to get $t(v)$ and use it in the second one

$$ t(v) = \frac{T}{\pi} \cos^{-1} \left( 1- \frac{\pi v}{T} \right) $$

$$ s(v) = \frac{T^2}{\pi^2} \cos^{-1} \left( 1- \frac{\pi v}{T} \right) - T \sqrt{ \frac{2 T v}{\pi^3} - \frac{v^2}{\pi^2} } $$

Comment: The purpose of my query is an experimental attempt to operate a track mounted vehicle (powered by a variable frequency drive) which has a position measuring transducer, and to guide it to a stop at a specific position.  I have already succeeded controlling it using constant acceleration, using v=SQRT(2AS).  I am attempting to improve by reducing the jerk in the system with the acceleration I proposed.  I had a typo in my original question in that the acceleration is Amax * sin(pi * t/T).  However I need v(s), not s(v).  I recognize my calculus is rusty.  Thanks

Comment: $v(s)$ does not exists analytically. This is because $s(t)$ cannot be solved for $t$ since it is of the form $t=a \sin(t)$. Otherwise you could state $v(s) = v(t(s))$ from $v(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Based on your input, I instead created a spreadsheet table of normalized s and v values.  I can now accomplish the goal using a table lookup.

Comment: So my answer was useful. Great.